# How to find the most frequent letters and the number of occurrences, using Stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have List with single letters inside. I need to count all duplicates and find the most frequent duplicate. The list generates randomly, so it may contain several most frequent letters.

Is it possible to create only one map inside one Stream or put the second map inside Stream? I need only one Stream chain, using the method groupingBy().

```
public static void mostFrequentlyDuplicateLetters(List<String> letters) {   
     Map<String, Long> collect = letterList
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::valueOf, Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(// How to find the most frequent letters and put them on a map?))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
        }
```

Comment: How does the posted code relate to your question?

Comment: This method does the same task, but I need another implementation.

Comment: I have changed the code. But I still need ideas.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use the `Stream` API? This feels like something you could just do manually.

Comment: Yes, I have some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it may contain several most frequent letters

The solution below allows to determine `all the letters` from the given list that have a `maximum frequency`.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Long> frequencies = getFrequencyMap(List.of("A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "B", "D"));
        long max = getMaxFrequency(frequencies);
        System.out.println("max = " + max);
        System.out.println(mostFrequentlyDuplicateLetters(frequencies, max));
    }
```

```
    public static Map<String, Long> getFrequencyMap(List<String> letters) {
        return letters.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(UnaryOperator.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    }
```

```
    public static long getMaxFrequency(Map<String, Long> frequencies) {
        return frequencies.values().stream()
                .mapToLong(Long::longValue)
                .max()
                .orElse(0);
    }
```

```
    public static List<String> mostFrequentlyDuplicateLetters(Map<String, Long> frequencies, 
                                                              long frequency) {
        return frequencies.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == frequency)
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

**output** (both letters `B` and `C` have frequency = 3)

```
max = 3
[B, C]
```

> Is it possible to create only one map inside one Stream

If you want your code to be both efficient and clean the answer is `NO`. By trying to fuse more than one concern in one method you'll violate the first of the **SOLID** principles - **`The single responsibility principle`**.

Comment: Thank you, this is good solution! Дякую! :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all what you need as your return type is actually `Map.Entry`, not the whole Map, since you just want an entry with highest number of occurrences.

You can try this way:

```java
   public Map.Entry<String,Long> mostFrequentlyDuplicateLetters(List<String> letterList){
        return letterList
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::valueOf, Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                .get();
    }
```

Comment: `1.`  method `get() ` throws NoSuchElementException, if there's no guarantee that there always be a value, "orElseThrow()` must be used instead because it makes the intention clearer. `2.` the question is `"find the most frequent letters" ` - you solution is capable to find only one letter.